# jQuery in Wamp Server

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I just installed Wamp server on my pc. I also installed Wordpress. Everything seems working fine except jQuery features like when I click to see the widgets they do not expand in Admin screen. All other dropdown menu do not expand. Here is a screenshot: http://s14.postimg.org/42d9hrx69/screenshot_15.png

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this article on the WAMPServer forum.

It was always a good idea to create a Virtual Hosts to run WordPress in. It helps to stops things like this happening.

[WAMPServer 2.5 The Homepage, Your Projects Menu and the need for Virtual Hosts](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,124482)

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly! Thanks for your comment. I have gone through the link and I am confused if the link could solve my problem. Also when I edited C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file and clicked saved, it shows me a message "Please check if the file is opended in another program"

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. It seems that the problem was with my wordpress files so I downloaded a fresh version wordpress and installed it. Now everything works very fine. Thanks